# Postgres Container deployed to EBS but not running when ssh into EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecr

I am deploying a multistage docker container with React,Node,Postgres and Nginx. I used codepipeline for this. Problem here is here I am able to successfully run, tag and deploy to the containers available in ECR, but when I ssh into EC2 instance which is created by and managed by EBS Environment, and executed `docker ps` I am **unable to see the database container here**, all the other three containers are available here , but database container is not running, because of that I am unable to communicate with the Postgres Database.

My **docker-compose-prod.yml** file

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nginx
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
  app:
    image: XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/app
    build:
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./api:/app
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
  client:
    image: XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/client
    build:
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  db:
    image: XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/db
    build:
      context: ./postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db-data:
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "client",
      "image": "XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/client",
      "hostname": "client",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 256
    },
    {
      "name": "app",
      "image": "XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/app",
      "hostname": "app",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 128
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nginx",
      "hostname": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": ["client", "app"],
      "memory": 64
    },
    {
      "name": "db",
      "image": "XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/db",
      "hostname": "db",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 256
    }
  ]
}
```